# I am trying to figure out how to properly loops mouse events

Tags: java

Im working on an assignment where an image moves around and when the user clicks on the panel the image stops.  When the user clicks on the panel again the image starts.   As of now i can only start and stop the image once before it stays going. I need help to loop this process so that the user can keep starting and stopping the image.

Here is my code

Main:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rebound {
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Displays the main frame of the program.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rebound");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.getContentPane().add(new ReboundPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Panel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReboundPanel extends JPanel
{

   private final int DELAY = 10, IMAGE_SIZE = 35;

   private ImageIcon image;
   private Timer timer;
   private int x, y, moveX, moveY;

   public ReboundPanel()
   {
      timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ReboundListener());
      addMouseListener (new StopListener());
      image = new ImageIcon ("happyFace.gif");

      x = 0;
      y = 40;
      moveX = moveY = 3;

      setPreferredSize (new Dimension(1900, 1000));
      setBackground (Color.black);
      timer.start();
   }


   public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
   {
      super.paintComponent (page);
      image.paintIcon (this, page, x, y);
   }


   private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
         x += moveX;
         y += moveY;

         if (x <= 0 || x >= 1900-IMAGE_SIZE)
            moveX = moveX * -1;

         if (y <= 0 || y >= 1000-IMAGE_SIZE)
            moveY = moveY * -1;

         repaint();
      }
   }

   //  Represents the action listener for the timer.

   public class StopListener extends MouseAdapter
   {

       public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
   {

            if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                timer.stop();
            }

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                    {
                        timer.start();
                        removeMouseListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reuse the same listener, and check the state of the timer before starting/stopping it:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
{
    if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
    {
        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
        }
        else {
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like your solution better. Forgot that timer has an `isRunning()`.

Comment: google brought me straight here. Clear OP code & clear answer. helped me learn

Answer (score 1):

In you `StopListener` class have an instance variable `bool isMoving = true;`

Then in your handler should use that to determine whether to stop or start the timer:

```
public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent event )
{
    if( event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 )
    {
        if( isMoving )
            timer.stop();
        else
            timer.start();

        isMoving = !isMoving;
    }
}
```